# How to set up a dashboard at my startup?

Tags: hardware-rec, dashboard

We have a spare high-resolution monitor (23" 1920x1080) at work that we want to turn into a 'dashboard' in a common area that would display performance metrics from our service.

What type of hardware should we look at using for this? A netbook? A fanless PC? Is there any specialized low-power, quiet hardware that I could use to load up a website all day long and display it on such a high-res monitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up buying the cheapest netbook we could find and hooking it up to our monitor via VGA. I was surprised but that little machine was easily able to power such a high-res display. Note that we're not playing video, just showing a web-based dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need anything with much power just to display a web page.

You could happily run this on say a small Atom based embedded system (Micro ATX) with a small flash-based OS on say a CF card.

Comment: Well.. just enough to run a good enough desktop environment to make the webpage look good (OS styled buttons, sufficient css/js support), like Chrome or Opera on Xfce.